# Css code for multiple Ids

Tags: css

my font is to be #fff and the mouse over is #3cf.

I am confused how to write the css using multiple Ids and the a:hover.

https://jsfiddle.net/zpupster/0mg4cyLs/

```
#btn1, #btn2, #btn3
{
    background-color: #003399;
    color: #FFF;
}
  #btn1, #btn2, #btn3, a:hover
{
    color:#3cf;
}
```

thanks...

Comment: #btn1 a:hover, #btn2 a:hover, #btn3 a:hover

Comment: also, consider using classes instead of IDs for assigning the same behavior to many different objects. You can easily mix & match classes and save a lot of pseudo-micro-managing this way

Comment: Why bother with the ids? You could just define rules for `a` and `a:hover`. And if it's only a select group of `a` tags you could use `.btn-group > a` in your example.

Comment: Use classes instead of `IDs`, if you had 20 buttons you would have to include `#btn1, #btn2, #btn3 .... #btn20`, whereas a class would just be `.btn { background-color: #003399; color: #FFF; }`, and you could add that class to all links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct, the `a`-tag is a child of your `#btn*`-tags. Than you need to write your code like this:

```
#btn1, #btn2, #btn3
{
    background-color: #003399;
    color: #FFF;
}

#btn1 a:hover,
#btn2 a:hover, 
#btn3 a:hover
{
    color:#3cf;
}
```

In this case the `color` property will be applied to the `a`-tag in the`#btn*`-tags if the mouse hovers the `a`-tag.
It is also possible to apply the `color` property to the `#btn*`-tag if the mouse hover them:

```
#btn1:hover,
#btn2:hover, 
#btn3:hover
{
    color:#3cf;
}
```

You should read a Little bit more about CSS Selectors. There is a [good overview on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#btn1, 
#btn2, 
#btn3 {
    background-color: #003399;
    color: #FFF;
}
#btn1:hover, 
#btn2:hover, 
#btn3:hover, 
a:hover {
    color:#3cf;
}
```